# Go back from an imported js object file to the file where it was CMD + clicked in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio on MacOS SIERRA with a JS project you are able to go to the file where an imported object is exported from by pressing CMD + click the object. For example:

```
import { UpdateProfileMutation } from '../../../graphql/mutations';
```

When you CMD + click the UpdateProfileMutation you are directed to the mutations file where UpdateProfileMutation is exported from. It is a valuable feature. But the problem is that the current file where the above code resides is closed when the new file opens. This is a problematic behaviour because you often want to quickly look in a file and then go back to the file it is imported to. So my question is: can you force CMD + click to open a new tab with the file? Or is there a keyboard shortcut for going back from the file you have just clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior when opening a file in Visual Studio Code is to open it in preview mode.

This will show the file name *italicized* in the editor tab, and will replace this specific tab with the next file you open unless you specify that you want to `keep this editor`.

There are multiple ways to do achieve what you are after:

Tell Visual Studio Code to `keep the current editor` before moving to another file, the shortcut for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can look up the shortcut on Mac using the command palette, it should be <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> though.

You could also disable preview mode for opening files according to your needs with these two settings:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
```